# Objective C Using 2D Arrays with cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, multidimensional-array

I know the basic idea of using arrays with cellForRowAtIndexPath using indexPath and row, but I'm unsure of the best way to go through a 2D array.  I've created a custom cell that accepts 7 different strings into 7 holders and I've created a 2D array that has 3 rows of 7 strings. (3x7 2D array).  Any suggestions on how to set up the cellForRowAtIndexPath to automatically go through this array?

Let me go into more detail.  My multidimensional-array is an array of arrays that contain 7 strings: ("Potato", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")  My custom cell is all set up with 7 subviews (they work, I tested it with an array).  In the same class that I create the custom cell, I've created a method that assigns values from the test array to those subviews:

```
- (void)setMyArray:(NSArray *)myArray
{
   NSString *name = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
   [nameLabel setText:name];
   [name release];
   NSString *numberA = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
   [aLabel setText:numberA];
   [numberA release];
   NSString *numberB = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
   [bLabel setText:numberB];
   [numberB release];
   NSString *numberC = [myArray objectAtIndex:3];
   [cLabel setText:numberC];
   [numberC release];
   NSString *numberD = [myArray objectAtIndex:4];
   [dLabel setText:numberD];
   [numberD release];
   NSString *numberE = [myArray objectAtIndex:5];
   [eLabel setText:numberE];
   [numberE release];
   NSString *numberF = [myArray objectAtIndex:6];
   [fLabel setText:numberF];
   [numberF release];
}
```

In the viewController, all I have to call is:

```
[cell setMyArray:testList];
```

And it works.  I'm just not sure how to do it with a 2D array.

Comment: It will depend on how you have configured your 2D array.

Comment: The above will crash eventually. You're over-releasing every element in your array. The call to `-objectAtIndex:` is not an alloc, copy or retain, so you should not be calling `release` on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly your custom cell code looks like, but wouldn't you just do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
       //...
    }

    [cell setMyArray:[self.myTwoDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // and so on...
```

Also, Rob's right about your memory management. Don't release the objects as you take them out of the original array.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the memory management tips.  And yeah, you were right Josh, your code works great.  I figured out with some NSLogs that my setMyArray worked perfectly fine and didn't need a second objectAtIndex.  It received an array every time.  Thanks again guys.

Comment: An `NSArray` inside another is still an `NSArray`, so that's what you get when you ask for `objectAtIndex:` Glad I could help!